# Scala Play 2.4 - dynamically pick up configuration updates

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework-2.0, sbt

At the moment -my use of Play's (epic) hot compilation doesn't pick up (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Configuration) conf/application.conf changes.

I have a feeling that is a relatively expected occurrence. I tend to shut down sbt and restart it for things to take effect.

Is there perhaps a smaller amount of 'sbt restarting' I can do to get config changes picked up?

Comment: `sbt reload` will do the trick, but you'll still need to restart the application (i.e. `cmd + d` in console, then `run` again)

Comment: Yup; that is quicker for me; thanks!